# How to make coc show linting popup no matter where the cursor is on the line?

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

I recently moved from ALE to coc.nvim as the intellisense was not that great with ALE.
But i see one problem with the error or warnings popup. The cursor needing to be exactly on the underlined error.

Is there a way i can make coc show the popup no matter where the cursor is on the line?

I know i can use the commands to goto next and prev error. But i think this would make some things easier.

Answer (score 12):

In your `coc-settings.json` file write:

```sh
{
 "diagnostic.checkCurrentLine": true
}
```

`coc-settings.json` can be found in ~/.vim/coc-settings.json

OR

in vim type `:CocConfig` to go to that file

Answer (score 9):

In your `coc-settings.json` file (you can type `:CocConfig` if you are already in Vim as the other answer stated) add the following lines:

```json
{
  ...
  "diagnostic.virtualText": true,
  "diagnostic.virtualTextCurrentLineOnly": false
}
```

Then close your vim instance and open it again or type `:CocRestart` to restart Coc. You should see coc's errors and warnings even if you are not stepping in that line.

Answer (score 0):

use `:CocList diagnostics`
https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Using-coc-list#builtin-list-sources

or `lopen` if you enable this parameter.
https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/afbe23851a6eb4a81a160c0d3e3feec5a27fd7a2/doc/coc.txt#L360